# GET vs. POST in Session Validation

Tags: security, validation, rest, post, get

So I just read [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you/) article by Jeff Atwood and I wanted to make sure I understand it correctly as to how it applies to my use case. I am trying to validate a session for silent login. For security purposes this should be done with a POST right? Does it matter? I am just passing the sessionID and username from the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to CSRF (Cross-site request forgery), you can cause a user to take any action on any site which they are logged in to provided that the action requires only a GET. Forcing this to be done over a POST request defeats the approach of embedding an image, script tag, whatever in another page.

Even POST isn't completely secure in this scenario. There are other ways to mount a CSRF attack on a site using POST. Clickjacking/UI-Redressing enables another site to trick a user into submitting a form to a different website.

Basically the best way to validate is to add an automatically generated, hidden form element. You can store this inside your session data (Example: `$_SESSION` for PHP) so that you only need to generate a token at the start of a session. Of course, an attack could try do something like clickjacking (mentioned above) in combination with a iframe pointing directly to your site and possibly some JS to hide things a little.

For anything important you should re-prompt the user for their password, thereby greatly diminishing the value of any successful CSRF attacks.